# I want to know the source files for this liferay 6.2 search portlet(jsp and java)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I am working in liferay 6.2 search portlet. I want to know the source files for this search portlet(jsp and java). I have searched the files in my whole project but i cant find the files. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Here are locations you are looking for:

> portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/search/..
>
> portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/search/..

Answer (score 0):

JSP files can be found inside ROOT
1. /html/portlet/search
2. /html/taglib/ui/search (start.jsp)

For java files open portal-impl.jar file and search for all search API classes.

Answer (score 0):

And if you really want the source - past and future versions of it - then please visit: [Liferay Portal Github Page](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal)